# How to split tool windows on right vertically again?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

In Visual Studio 2008 I somehow dragged around my tool windows so that now

- Solution Explorer
- Database Explorer
- Class Explorer
- Properties

are all in one long vertical tool window on the side. Now matter how I move them around, undock, unhide, hide, dock them, I can't get them back to how they were.

What do I have to do so that:

- Solution Explorer
- Database Explorer
- Class explorer

are on the top half on the right, and:

- Properties

is on the bottom half?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the tab for "Properties" and drag up, you should see the 9 drop hints on your screen. You want the bottom one in the "five-leaf" clover that is in the middle of the toolbar window.

If all else fails, Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset all settings.

Comment: nice, I thought I had tried that in all my dragging and dropping but apparently now, thanks!